# Calculating H-Bridge without motor specifications

Tags: motor, design, h-bridge

I am currently calculating elements for an H-Bridge for brushed dc motor and PWM speed control that operates on 6V and maximum current of 2A. However I want it to work with different 6V brushed DC motors, depending on its use and here comes my issue:

How do I calculate decoupling capacitors, motor terminal capacitors and working frequency when I have no specific Lm and Rm of the motor itself?

Comment: Why are you designing a discrete component bridge for an unconstrained application in a territory that already seems to be covered by modern IC bridges?  Conversely, if you have an application but have not chosen the motor, perhaps you should look at the range of *possible* motors.

Comment: Your power supply will fail if  \$(Rm+RdsOn)< 6V/2A\$

Comment: I suggest you use low ESR battery and charger (>10kfarads rather than just caps to DC supply or use a PC 12V PSU and converter

Comment: http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/index.php/Driving_a_high_current_DC_Motor_using_an_H-bridge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use >6A DC-DC supply and 40A FETs 10mΩ or 1% of linear R min load to supply.  Supply ESR must be < 1% of V/I so large low ESR e-caps are also needed. 1mF (10mΩ @ 15kHz) **A battery of sufficient low ESR and Ah will have > 10k Farads capacitance.**

## My suggestion : RdsOn=1% of Vdc/Ir

Choose the following variables:

\$\omega_I\$ = motor current commutation frequency
\$\omega_R \$ = typ. 82% max no load RPM
\$I_{R}\$  = Rated full load current at full power
\$V_{dc}\$ = Rated  DC voltage
\$Z_L({\omega_I})=\dfrac{V_{dc}}{I_R( \omega_I )}=\$
=  Motor  apparent full load impedance
\${I_{start}}\$  startup current at rated Vdc, (typ. \$I_{start}=10I_R\$+/-25%)
\$I_{max} \$ = desired max % of \$I_{start}\$  by controlling PWM or Vdc profile vs RPM  or field current
\$a_{pu}\$ [%] = \$\dfrac{I_{max}}{I_{start}}\$  desired or resulting max acceleration per unit of max in [%]
\$R_{on}\$ = MOSFET RdsOn in half-bridge
\$P_L{_{pu}}\$    = sum of all power losses as a %pu of total power at max rating
\$P_C{_{pu}}\$ = conduction loss due to \$R_{on}\$  of MOSFET in half-bridge with dead-time

## Reasons

**If RdsOn=1% of Vdc/Ir then Rdson = 10% Rm**
If using a dual half-bridge motor [Rm + 2R_{on}] x # of phases
Thus 1% conduction loss at rated power and 10% of startup conduction losses (+/-25%) then Rm + 10% Rm  means startup current reduces 10% and bridges losses are equal to rated motor power but only for brief startup time. So heatsink must handle this and be current limited/ thermally protected.